# Как вывести ip всех DNS серверов?

Tags: linux, shell

Как определить IP-адреса всех используемых DNS-серверов?

Через терминал и через файл shell

Comment: dns-серверов в интернете — огромное количество. уточните, пожалуйста, свой вопрос. внести изменения можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса.

Comment: судя по [этому «ответу»](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/536402/178576) вас интересует(-ют) dns-сервер(-ы), используемый(-е) вашей системой. смотрите содержимое файла `/etc/resolv.conf`

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

операционная система использует dns-серверы, перечисленные в файле `/etc/resolv.conf` в виде строк формата:

```
nameserver ip-адрес
```

посмотреть всё содержимое этого файла можно, например, командой:

```
$ cat /etc/resolv.conf
```

вывести только строки, начинающиеся с `nameserver` (обычно их не более трёх), можно, например, так:

```
$ grep ^nameserver /etc/resolv.conf
```

вывести только ip-адреса из таких строк можно, например, так:

```
$ sed -n 's/^nameserver\s\+//p' /etc/resolv.conf
```

Comment: Ubuntu 15.04, установлен пакет dnsmasq-base как кэширующий прокси, управляется NetworkManager-ом. Ваш метод выдаёт 127.0.1.1, что с одной стороны правда, но не та информация, которую хотелось узнать.

Comment: @sercxjo, для вашего случая 127.0.0.1 — это и есть ответ на **данный** вопрос. а то, что вам, вероятно, хотелось бы узнать — это ведь совершенно другой вопрос, который ещё и сформулировать надо.